# PFQuery includeKey doesn't seem to be working: Key data unavailible

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, objective-c-2.0

I am building a social app and am currently building a PFQueryTable View Controller that I would like to display a list of followers for the user selected in a previous screen.

under queryForTable i have the below query set:

```
-(void) queryForTable {

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"follow"];
    [query whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.user];
    [query whereKey:@"toUser" notEqualTo:self.user];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"toUser"];
    [query includeKey:@"toUser"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];

    return query;

}
```

When I perform a NSLog for object under cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (FollowViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *FollowCellIdentifier = @"FriendCell";

    FollowViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FollowCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FollowViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FollowCellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"OBJECT IS %@",object);


    cell.userLabel.text = [[object objectForKey:@"toUser"] objectForKey:@"username"];



        return cell;
}
```

the result is

> OBJECT IS  {
>       ACL = "";
>       fromUser = "";
>       toUser = "";
>       type = follow; }

If I try to then create:

```
cell.userLabel.text = [[object objectForKey:@"toUser"] objectForKey:@"username"];
```

The console gives me an error of:

> 'Key "username" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its
>   value.'

If I step the process with breaks,the userLabel.text populates fine. but if I run it without the breaks I always get the error. Is there something I am missing here?

Any help would be great as I have been trying to fix this for the past 4 days.

Comment: Note that the keys used in the query code begin with capital letters, but the keys logged do not.

Comment: Just checked that the correct typing is "toUser" and "fromUser" I have checked this in my code and its correct, was a typing error for this question.

Comment: Problem is still occuring by the way.

Comment: Can you show the code you have for cellForRow

Comment: I have added my cellForRow code as it currently stands within the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[object objectForKey:@"toUser"];
[user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
  cell.userLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
}];
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it still complains that the key data isn't available. I have tried changing  it to fetch and fetchifneeded but still the same. It's almost like the data isn't being grabbed fast enough, is that even possible?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: This works! Placing it into cellForRowAtIndex did the job very well, thank you very much. I think i just needed a couple of days to step away from this and re-apply your recommendation. Thanks so much everyone!